# How to select data from phpmyadmin when we fetch data in php page. when user select any data in dropdown menu and it answer return from Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

[This phpmyadmin and in this dbname is inzetank and table name is intzetankstandard, i want fetch data from this db into my .php file how can?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgeuI.png)[this is dropdown menu, if i select any data from this menu then i want ans from my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tc66.png)

Comment: I cannot imagine that this is something that would happen in phpmyadmin

Comment: i solved it :) , in this portion i confused in syntax but now i solved it

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a form tag eg-

```
<form id="teacher" method="post">
```

Then your select or input fields-

```
<select name="concrate_grade">
<option value="25"></option>
</select>
<input type="text" size="50" name="department">
```

And then your submit-

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
```

In your php you have to take the value by name once form is submitted-

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{
$department=$_POST['department'];
$concrate_grade= $_POST['concrate_grade'];
```

Now in your php you have your concrate_grade value selected in your $concrate_grade variable.

Now get the data as you require from your database in mysql-

```
$query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE concrate_grade=$concrate_grade"); 
$count=mysqli_num_rows($query); 
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
// do whatever with this row
}
```